# \datetime don't work in \index

Tags: glossaries, indexing, datetime

I'm building a complex index of dates & I'm using a lot of home commands. All is ok except using `\datetime` commands with argument for exemple

```
\newcommand*{\qd}[1]{\ordinalnum{#1}~siècle\index{\ordinalnum{#1}~siècle}}
\qd{8}
```

It don't made the entry in the index. I show you all my file :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}                    
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}         
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime} 
\usepackage[xindy={language=french, codepage=utf8}, style=altlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[xindy, splitindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}

\renewcommand{\fmtord}[1]{\up{#1}}
\makeatletter\patchcmd{\@ordinalMfrench}{eme}{ème}{}{}\makeatother

\makeglossaries
\def\xindylangopt{-M lang/french/utf8-lang -M style1.xdy}
\makeindex[name=can, title=Index des dates, options=\xindylangopt, intoc]

\newglossaryentry{Test 1}{name = Test 1, description = {Test 1 glossaire}}
\newglossaryentry{Test 2}{name = Test 2, description = {Test 2 glossaire}}

\newcommand*{\qds}[1]{\ordinalnum{#1}~siècle\index[can]{\ordinalnum{#1}~siècle}}
\newcommand*{\qdo}[1]{\ordinalnum{#1}~siècle\index[can]{{#1}~siècle}}

\begin{document}
\gls{Test 1}, \gls{Test 2}, 
\qds{8}, \qdo{9}, Test index\index[can]{Test index}
\printindex[can]
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

I compile with that :

```
% xelatex Date.tex
% makeglossaries Date
% xelatex -shell-escape Date.tex
% xelatex Date.tex
```

An idea ? How find a solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either it is a bug or a feature, but `\ordinalnum` fails somehow inside the `\index[can]{...}` command, it does not like `[]` due to some reason unknown to me.

The workaround is to use `\ordinal` which uses a counter. I defined a dummy counter, which is fed with the century number (1st argument) and then use `\ordinal` inside the commands `qds` and `qdo`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}                    
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}         
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime} 
\usepackage[xindy={language=french, codepage=utf8}, style=altlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[xindy, splitindex]{imakeidx}

\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}
%%%% Commented out since font is not installed on my computer
%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}

\renewcommand{\fmtord}[1]{\up{#1}}%
\makeatletter\patchcmd{\@ordinalMfrench}{eme}{ème}{}{}\makeatother

\makeglossaries
\def\xindylangopt{-M lang/french/utf8-lang -M style1.xdy}
\makeindex[name=can, title={Index des dates}, options={\xindylangopt}, intoc]
\makeindex[name=can,title={Index des dates}]


\newglossaryentry{Test 1}{name = Test 1, description = {Test 1 glossaire}}
\newglossaryentry{Test 2}{name = Test 2, description = {Test 2 glossaire}}


%%%%%% My additions and workaround ---> instead of using the number directly
%%%%%% store the number to a dummy counter and use \ordinal instead of \ordinalnum


\newrobustcmd{\ProvideOrdinalCounter}[1]{%
\ifltxcounter{#1}{%
}{%
\newcounter{#1}%
}%
}% End Of \ProvideOrdinalCounter


\newcommand{\qds}[1]{%
\setcounter{CenturyCounter}{#1}%
\ordinal{CenturyCounter}~siècle\index[can]{\ordinal{CenturyCounter}~siècle}%
}%

\newcommand{\qdo}[1]{%
  \setcounter{CenturyCounter}{#1}%
  \ordinal{CenturyCounter}~siècle\index[can]{\ordinal{CenturyCounter}~siècle}%
}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
 \ProvideOrdinalCounter{CenturyCounter}%
}%



\begin{document}
\gls{Test 1}, \gls{Test 2}, 
\qds{8}, \qdo{9}, Test index\index[can]{Test index}
\printindex[can]
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I'll test… It's a good way using counters !

Answer (score 4):

The fix is easy:

```
\newcommand*{\qds}[1]{%
  \ordinalnum{#1}~siècle%
  \index[can]{\protect\ordinalnum{#1}~siècle}%
}
```

Here's the index (I removed the `style1`, of course, and also the call `\qdo{8}` call).

[image]

And here's the `.ind` file

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroupDefault{default}
  \item \ordinalnum {8}~siècle, 1

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{T}
  \item Test index, 1

\end{theindex}
```

Comment: It's the easier answer. Thank you very much